# How to maintain Google Drive tree structure while having advanced ACL permissions?

Tags: google-drive-api

My question concerns Google Drive.

I would like to know how to maintain the same tree structure for all my users accross the organization when I share it. While keeping advanced and customizable ACL permissions for folders and sub-folders.

I am the admin of my Google Business Apps and my Drive folder tree is very well organized and structured. I want some users of my organization to be added to a folder "A" so they can access a sub-folder "A.1", but not the other sub-folders "A.2" and "A.3".

Right now it is pretty messy and hectic if I want to save my tree structure. Indeed, if I want to save my tree structures in my users' Drive, I have to give them access to the main folder "A" so they will be able to access sub-folder "A.1". However, if I do it, my users will be automatically able to access the other sub-folders 1.2. and 1.3. (because the person has access to the main folder "A"). Therefore, I have to manually restrict the access to the sub-folder "A.1" only. That's a pain.

When I give to my users access to the folder "A.1" only, the folder is shared individually and my users' Drive tree structure is no more organized. After sharing 20 folders, my users' Drive becomes pretty messy, while mine remains completely clean (since I created the tree structure and I have all the permissions).

Does anyone know how to efficiently share an identically Drive tree structure among the whole organization, without compromizing on the ACL?

Thanks,
B.

PS: The only post related to this problem is here but it doesn't answer my question: [Google Drive - Change owner on folder, sub-folders and content, while saving tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030587/google-drive-change-owner-on-folder-sub-folders-and-content-while-saving-tre)

Comment: Love this question. I've been baffled trying to get my head around a good structure with appropriate permissions. The whole workflow for Google Drive Sharing is a hot mess when compared to my experience of traditional shared folders.

Comment: I have the same issue... +1

Answer (score 0):

Regrettably, Google Team drive does not currently allow assigning permissions to team drive sub-folders or sharing symlinks across team folders. :(

As a result, our organization ended up creating dozens of team folders each based on role access.  This approach solved several problems but created others and makes it hard to share content between roles.

Ideally... GOOGLE should update Team drive to allow permissions to be managed at the drive as well as subfolder level.   Until they do the only way to share content within a team drive across roles is one file at a time.